# Selenium webdriver не работает с PayPal Sandbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, paypal

Selenium Webdriver не видит элементов на странице PayPal. Вот пример:

```
drive.get("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8BH551637R395150X#/checkout/login")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')))
drive.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys("xxx@gmail.com")
```

получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Scripts\nim\Testdriver Page\Several gifts redeem\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    Functions.drive.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys("xxx@gmail.com")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 266, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 744, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.53.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.102)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```